# Unique rows of a column based on different levels of another column

Tags: r

I have a dataframe like this with 30000 rows:

```
    gene     logFC    adj.p.val disease
1  SYT11 1.9678590 3.542121e-09      DN
2   PPT1 0.7349565 5.239188e-09      DN
3 PHLDA2 2.7419282 5.478323e-08      DN
4  TGFBI 1.6491225 5.478323e-08      DN
5  CRIP1 1.6476587 2.342271e-07      DN
6  TIGAR 1.2751720 2.342271e-07      DN
```

The levels of disease column are

```
levels(as.factor(pfilter_hdata$disease))
[1] "DN"       "FSGS"     "FSGS-MCD" "HN"       "IgAN"     "LN"       "MCD"      "MGN"      "RPGN"
```

What I would like to do is to extract the unique genes for each disease against all others. For example, in case of DN i want to create a file with all genes present in DN but not in all other diseases. How can I do this in R?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pivot the data wider and filter the rows that only sum to 1:

```r
library(tidyverse)


dat <- tibble(gene = c("abc", "123", "u&me", "acc", "123", "zzz", "efd", "123", "abc"),
       disease = c(rep("DN", 3), rep("FSGS", 3), rep("LN", 3)))


dat %>%
  mutate(val = 1) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = disease, values_from = val, values_fill = 0) %>%
  filter(rowSums(.[,2:ncol(.)]) == 1) 
#> # A tibble: 4 x 4
#>   gene     DN  FSGS    LN
#>   <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 u&me      1     0     0
#> 2 acc       0     1     0
#> 3 zzz       0     1     0
#> 4 efd       0     0     1
```

Another option is to summarize the number of unique genes and filter if there is more than 1:

```r
library(tidyverse)


dat |>
  reframe(gene = unique(gene), .by = disease) |>
  mutate(n = n(), .by = gene) |>
  filter(n == 1)
#> # A tibble: 4 x 3
#>   disease gene      n
#>   <chr>   <chr> <int>
#> 1 DN      u&me      1
#> 2 FSGS    acc       1
#> 3 FSGS    zzz       1
#> 4 LN      efd       1
```

The second method is likely more efficient.

Comment: Thank you ! yes second option looks more efficient

Comment: How can i split it and include the original columns to those that corespond to n=1? I should split and then use intersect or join or there is a quicker way ? The result will be new dataframe for each disease with only the genes with n=1 and the corresponding columns from input file